# Wrong overload selected when implicity converting to a const type

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

// General overload using a template
template <typename SomeType>
void some_func(const SomeType p) {
    std::cout << "Using the general function" << std::endl;
}

// Specific overload, accepting a 'const double*' type
void some_func(const double* p) {
    std::cout << "Using the function accepting a const double*" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // This one uses the specific overload, as expected
    const double *a = new double(1.1);
    some_func(a);
    delete a;
    
    // This one uses the general function rather than the second overload
    double *b = new double(1.1);
    some_func(b);
    delete b;
    
    return 0;
}
```

In this piece of code, there are two overloads of the `some_func` function. The first one is the most general overload, using a template to capture practically any type. The second overload is a specific overload, accepting a `const double*` type as its argument.

In the `main` function, I first create the variable `a` of type `const double*`. When supplying `a` to `some_func`, the second overload is selected. This is as expected. Secondly, I create a variable `b` of type `double*` (so no `const`). When supplying the variable `b` to `some_func`, it selects the first overload. I would've expected it to select the second overload, as (I think) it should be able to implicitly convert a type `double*` to `const double*`. Why does it select the first overload rather than the second overload in this case?

For completeness, this is the output of the program:

```sh
$ g++ main.cpp
$ ./a.out
Using the function accepting a const double*
Using the general function
```

Comment: Hint: what values do you expect `p` to have in each functoon?

Comment: The arguments shall match exactly for compiler to select the non-template function. So the selection is not "wrong".

Comment: Does it make sense why the template is preferred if you write the function as `void some_func(double const * p) ` which is equivalent to what you have?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica When passing `b` to `some_func`, I expected `p` to have the type `const double *` in both overloads. However, it turns out that `p` is of type `double* const` in the templated overload and of type `const double*` in the specific overload. Taking this into account, I understand why it uses the templated overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During template instantiation, this `const SomeType p` would turn into `double* const p` which is a better match than `const double*`. That is, the template's parameter would become a const-pointer to mutable data. 
In the template function, you can actually modify the data through that pointer, so it can be assumed it is a better match.
If you change `const SomeType p` to `const SomeType* p`, the specific overload will be selected.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Apart from changing `const SomeType p` to `const SomeType* p`, would there be any other way to make sure the specific overload is used when passing a `double *`? Unfortunately, the actual code does not allow for that change.

Comment: It depends on what your circumstances are. You could use SFINAE such as `std::enable_if`, or maybe check the type with `if constexpr()`. But if you can't change the template, then I think the only way you could do it is to add another specific overload that ideally matches the type and inside it you could just cast the value to const and call the original specific overload.

Answer (score 2):

The qualifier `const` is a kind of a contract. Here is means that the function won't be able to change the value by the pointer

So the compiler has two options:

1. Either to instantiate a function from template which will be able (potentially) to change the value.
2. Use the stricter function that won't be able to change it.

Having the argument which could be changed, it is logical to choose the first case.

So, following the rule of selecting with precise type, taking into account CV-qualifiers   very logical.